# how i can change or add shape behind the icon with BottomNavigationViewEx in android studio

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

I use BottomNavigationViewEx , and i want to do something like this in my Bottom Navigation , I want to change or add shape behind the icon and change position of the center item only .

[image]

I tried for position this function  bottomNavigationViewEx.setItemHeight(130) but all items move together.

for red circuit behind the center icon, I didn't find Solution.

Comment: Android is the technology, Android-Studio is just an IDE. Do you have problems with the IDE?

Comment: no I dont have problem with IDE, I forget to write Studio. just I want how to implement bottom Navigation like the picture

Comment: Didn't you even try to get the BottomNavigationBar?

Comment: yes i tried, i did exactly this https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/blob/master/read_me_images/no_animation_shifting_mode_item_shifting_mode_text.gif ..... just i want how to change or add shape behind the center  icon and change position of the center icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide center item from bottom navigation view. and put Fab button over bottom navigation view.This is code of bottom navigation layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"></View>

<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />




<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/bootomFab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="9dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is code for menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:title="fds"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_nothing"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@null"
    android:title="fxn"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_sync"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Comment: great, thanks.    but how i can set the FloatingButton inside the BottomNavigation bar, because i don't want the circle goes out of the Bottom bar ( see the picture )

Comment: Then create background as your image middle button and give fix height to ImageView and bottom view don't use floating action button instead use ImageView